# Could not find activesupport-5.0.0.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gem-bundler

I have done the 'bundle install' as the error message suggests, then I verified activesupport is installed using 'bundle show activesupport' which it is. Then I verified ruby is using the correct version that it was installed to, which it is. Now I'm at a loss and I keep getting the error message.

Here's the dev server:
http://ec2-52-34-168-122.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: It looks like you're using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 5 is not compatible with such an old version of Ruby.

Comment: ah! I'll check on that!